# How to delete big website?

Tags: web, ftp, hosting

I have a large website that I want to delete from my hosting account. What's the fastest way to do it? If I go with FTP client and select the whole root > delete, it'll probably take like an hour or more.

Anyone have good suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: which is your server?Linux /BSD?

Comment: @BhushanFirake I don`t thing he will as like this if his running an own server. Bcause this is just as an easy thing for a person who has setup a server before i think so..

Answer (score 0):

If you have this hosted on a hosting company best way is to

Submit a support request asking for them to delete it for you.

you are paying for them so why not ask them.?.